Multiple Cursors in Overleaf
I was minding my own business typing away in overleaf when suddenly (I must have hit some shortcut) two cursors appeared in the edit box. As I continued to type, text would appear from both cursors (you can see in the image a period (.) has been placed before each of them).
This feature seems to be not uncommon, but how can I activate it in future?


Hope this post should raise to Overleaf support, not here

If you press ctrl and click somewhere then the cursor will be duplicated in the new position. But indeed the question is borderline off-topic.
